# Netbeans SQL editor problems

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, netbeans, ucanaccess

I'm trying to use the Netbeans SQL editor to make some tests.
I've made the connection between Access and Netbeans with the UcanAccess's jars and no problem with it.

I can execute a select in the editor and everything ok, but it does not allow me to execute insert or update statements: This is the error.

> Error code 0, SQL state null: Unable to Connect to database

but the database is already connected and the select works great.

I've checked the permissions of `ACCESS BD` and `read only` is not marked.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, it had a solution. Discard UcanAccess.
UcanAccess actually can't work with a String in PK.
So we had to migrate to MySQL.